# Why is my HTTPS redirect not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have SSL installed, and it works when I put the `https://` in a link, the certificate is there and everything appears in order. Now, I'm trying to force `https` at all times for my admin folder by following some instructions I found on other questions here on SO. However, no approach seems to work for me.

This is what I'm trying (in .htaccess):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off
RewriteRule  ^/admin/$1  https://mydomain.com/admin/$1  [R=301,L,QSA]
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm on an Apache server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?admin/ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried a bunch of different methods I've found, nothing seems to work.

Comment: That works but I don't want to have the whole site in https, just the admin section.

Comment: Thanks, works now. Out of curiosity, what is the question mark (before "admin/") for?

Comment: I add this everytime just for be sure that the webserver config contains a tailing slash or not. This is maybe not nessesary but it does nothing bad so far the question mark says only the the character before is optional.